# Python - Is there a way to output results to pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following sample DF:

| Car Model | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| Mercedes Benz |  |
| Audi | 100000 |
| Renault | 50000 |

I have 2 calculations

1. Calculate the number of blank rows in the sales column

   missingSalesInfo = DF['Sales'].isnull().sum()

   missingSalesInfo = ("Number of missing values: ",missingSalesInfo)
2. Calculate the total car sales

totalSales = DF['Sales'].sum()

totalSales  = ("Total car sales: ",totalSales)

What I want to do is create a new DF, lets call it DF2 to store the above results.
See example below

**DF2**

| Description | Results |
| --- | --- |
| Number of missing values | 1 |
| Total car sales | 150000 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just a question of how to create a DataFrame. You can do that in a few ways, but here it's done with dictionary:

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Description': ['Number of missing values', 'Total car sales'], 
    'Results': [DF['Sales'].isnull().sum(), DF['Sales'].sum()]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.agg.html) with aggregate functions in dictionary, convert to integers and convert to `DataFrame` from `Series` by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html), for set new columns names is used [`DataFrame.set_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html):

```
df2 = (df['Sales'].agg({'Number of missing values': lambda x: x.isna().sum(),
                        'Total car sales': 'sum'})
                  .astype(int)
                  .reset_index()
                  .set_axis(['Description','Results'], axis=1)
                 )
print (df2)
                Description  Results
0  Number of missing values        1
1           Total car sales   150000
```

Alternative:

```
df2 = (df['Sales'].agg({'Number of missing values': lambda x: x.isna().sum(),
                       'Total car sales': 'sum'})
                  .astype(int)
                  .reset_index())

df2.columns = ['Description','Results']
```

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to do that. Here's a simple way.

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame()
df_2['Number of missing values'] =  DF['Sales'].isnull().sum()
df_2['Total car sales'] =  DF['Sales'].sum()`
```